# Does an object moving at a constant velocity have a force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, velocity

Force = mass $\times$ acceleration. So if a body is moving at a constant velocity of 160mph, does that mean the body has a force of $0$ Newtons?

Answer (score 7):

*Object do not have forces.*  Forces are things which *act on* objects.

If an object with constant mass has constant velocity, then we can say that there is no net force acting on it.

Answer (score -1):

You say $F=ma$... Not really, actually that is only if the mass is constant. Teh force is the rate of change of $mv$, and that is traduced as

$F= \frac{dm}{dt}\cdot v + m\cdot a$

Consequently, the only possible way for a body like that to **suffer** a force is that it is gaining/losing mass, altough it keeps its velocity constant.

Answer (score -2):

When the object collides with another it will cause an acceleration resulting in a force. However if it doesn't interact with anything then no, there is no force.